# Change the color of the source code text in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, editor

I would like to change the text color of the source code.

I do not know why at home it is clear on a white background so not very visible ...

thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps can you provide a picture or some code that you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Textarea of source code has a CSS class named `cke_source`, so just use something like this to make the text red for example:

```
textarea.cke_source {
    color: red;
}
```